# Проблема подключения компонентов в React js

Tags: reactjs, импорт, export, return

Доброго времени суток друзья.Возникла проблема подключения компонентов  в проекте React js.
Выводится такой код ошибки . Помогите разобратся .Заранее Спасибо.

```
/project/src/App.js
  9:9  warning  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  9:9  warning  Unreachable code                                                       no-unreachable

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:198
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:211
connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:258
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:49
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:44
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
webpackHotDevClient.js:198 ./src/components/Header.js

/project/src/components/Header.js
  6:4  warning  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  6:4  warning  Unreachable code                                                       no-unreachable

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:198
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:211
connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:258
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:49
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:44
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
webpackHotDevClient.js:198 ./src/components/Footer.js

/project/src/components/Footer.js
  6:4  warning  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  6:4  warning  Unreachable code                                                       no-unreachable

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:198
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:211
connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:258
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:49
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:44
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
webpackHotDevClient.js:198 ./src/components/Main.js

/project/src/components/Main.js
  6:4  warning  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  6:4  warning  Unreachable code                                                       no-unreachable

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)

printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:198
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:211
connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:258
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:49
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:44
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
```

Вот сам код

project/src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

project/src/App.js

```
import React  from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Main   from './components/Main';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

 function App()
 {
     return
        (   <div>
                <Header/>
                <Main/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>  
        );
 }


export default App;
```

/project/src/components/Header.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Header()
{
   return
   (
      <header>
         <h1>Hellow I am Header</h1>
      </header>   
   );
}


export default Header;
```

/project/src/components/Main.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Main()
{
   return
   (
        <main>
         <h1>Hellow I am Main</h1>
        </main>
   );
}


export default Main;
```

/project/src/components/Footer.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Footer()
{
   return
   (
       <footer>
         <h1>Hellow I am Footer</h1>
       </footer> 
   );
}


export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `return` сразу напишите скобки а не в следующей строке потому и ошибки у вас во всех компонентах.

Интерпретатор возвращает  `undefined` если написано таким образом `return` *(и в конце ничего)* поэтому не проверяет следующую строку от сюда и выводитсья ошибка потому что нету  `JSX` кода (*но он есть проста скобки не правильно поставлены*)

Пример как правильно:

```
return (
    <footer>
      <h1>Hellow I am Footer</h1>
    </footer>
);
```

Полный код:

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-forest-xn3gy)

```
function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer>
      <h1>Hellow I am Footer</h1>
    </footer>
  );
}


function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>Hellow I am Header</h1>
    </header>
  );
}

function Main() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Hellow I am Main</h1>
    </main>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Main />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ очень помогло.

Comment: @RiveraTimeClub всегда пожалуйста.